Variance of a weighted linear regression
$Y_i$ are independent random variables following a normal law of mean $m_i = Ax_i + B$ and variance $V.$
Let's take a sample $y_i \sim Y_i.$
I determine $a$ and $b,$ the weigthed least squares coefficients with weights $w_i$ of sum $1.$ I am interested in an unbiased estimator of variance $V.$
$$\sum w_i (y_i - a x_i - b)^2$$
is obviously biased but I don't manage to get anywhere close to a simple expression for an unbiased eatimate (In the case of the constant fit, it's fairly easier,see unbiased estimate of the variance of a weighted mean.)
Any ideas or references?
EDIT: for the unweighted regression, it's quite standard and a factor $n / (n - 2)$ is applied. But it won't work with weights (hint: take $w_1 = 0.$)

Rationale
I've been asked why I would need to assign different weights if all data points have the same variance.
I have two main cases from real life (physics):

The relative variances are known but the normalisation is unknown.  Thus the variances are $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2 / w_i$ with $w_i$ known but $\sigma$ remains to be determined.
The data follow a linear law only locally, so I want to filter out distant data with some weight function such as $w_i = \exp (-k^2 (x_i - x_0)^2)$.

Solution
I managed to come up with a solution.
Using $$x_i' = x_i - \sum_j w_j x_j$$ the biased estimator for the variance
$$\hat\sigma_\text{b}^2 = \sum_i w_i (y - a x_i - b)^2$$
can be written as
$$\hat\sigma_\text{b}^2 = \sum_i w_i y_i^2 - \left(\sum_i w_i y_i\right)^2 
- \frac{\left(\sum_i w_i x_i' y_i\right)^2}{\sum_i w_i x_i'^2} 
$$
To make the derivation easier, I will assume that the law I am trying to fit has $A=B=0$ so that $E(y_i) = 0$ and $E(y_i y_j) = \delta_{ij} \sigma^2$.  With that in mind I can expand the squares into double sums, notice that indices $i \ne j$ cancel and finally find that
$$\hat\sigma_\text{b}^2 = \sigma^2 - \left(\sum_i w_i^2 \right) \sigma^2
-\frac{\sum_i w_i^2 x_i'^2}{\sum_i w_i x_i'^2} \sigma^2$$
Thus I can write the unbiased estimate as
$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{N}{N - \Delta N_\text{free}} \hat\sigma_\text{b}$$
where
$$\Delta N_\text{free} = N \left[
   \sum_i w_i^2
 + \frac{\sum_i w_i^2 x_i'^2}{\sum_i w_i x_i'^2}
\right]$$
is the loss of degrees of freedom.  For equal weights ($w_i = 1/N$) it equals two, but will be larger than that for unequal weights.
Follow-up question
It seems simple enough that it must be somehow a well-known result. Any reference?

Often one uses weights proportional to the reciprocals of the variances, since that minimizes the variance of the least-squares estimators of $a$ and $b.$ But you are assuming the variances are all the same. Is there are reason for using some other weights?

This is a standard fact in the theory of linear statistical models. See e.g. formulas (4.5) and (4.7) in Chapter 4, which present the following unbiased estimator of the variance:
$$\hat\sigma^2=\frac1{n-2}\,
\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2-n\bar Y^2-\frac{\big(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)Y_i\big)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}\Big),$$
where $\bar Y:=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and $\bar x:=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.
(It is of course assumed here that $n\ge3$ and at least two of the $x_i$'s are distinct from each other.)

Yes, it is indeed standard in the unweighted case. However, in the weighted fit, it's no longer a n /  (n-2) correction.

What do you mean, precisely, by "in the weighted fit"? Why (and how) should an unbiased estimator of $V$ depend on your choice of estimators of $A$ and $B$? Also, using unequal weights given the same variance for all $i$ does not seem reasonable.

@loqueelviento : Do you a further response to my answer and comment?

Yes, I could answer my own question.  1. There are reasons for unequal weights (e.g. filter out distant data if law is linear only locally). 2. I don't understand your comment about A and B, I do not chose them, I try to fit them.

@loqueelviento : I have commented on your reasons for unequal weights. As for $A$ and $B$, I did not say that you chose them. Instead, I said you chose (weighted) estimators of $A$ and $B$. These estimators will depend on your choice of the weights. I also said that there is no reason to tie estimation of $V$ to your choice of estimators for $A$ and $B$.
